# Error when sending smtp email with google and codeigniter

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, smtp, gmail

trying to make a reset password function for my website however I cant get past sending an email without this error occuring.

> Unable to send email using PHP mail().
>   Your server might not be configured to
>   send mail using this method.

I am using gmail as the host to send the email. Here is the part of the function that is used to send the email.

$user_email = $this->input->post('email_address');

```
    $query = $this->db->get_where('account', array('email_address' => $user_email));
    if($query) {
        $config['protocal'] = 'smtp';
        $config['mail_path'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'USEREMAIL';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'PASSWORD';
        $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
        $config['mailtype'] = "html";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('matthew.attanasio135@gmail.com', 'Matthew');
        $this->email->to($user_email); 

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('<h1>Testing the email class.<h1>');  

        $this->email->send();
        if ( ! $this->email->send()) {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        } 
        else {
            echo('DONE');        
        }
```

I am also getting this error::

> Message: Undefined index: Subject

I do not understand why this is happening could you please help me out thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to send the email twice, the first time all your options are set and the second they aren't

change

```
    $this->email->send();
    if ( ! $this->email->send()) {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

to

```
    if ( ! $this->email->send()) {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

You should then get relevant errors if any remain.

Edit:

also change `$config['protocal']` to `$config['protocol']` to fix the sending problem

Comment: thanks your response fixed that problem however I am still getting an error as `The following SMTP error was encountered: 503 5.5.1 RCPT first. z10sm7618335wfj.12 
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. z10sm7618335wfj.12 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. z10sm7618335wfj.12 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.`

Comment: Try changing `$config['smtp_port'] = '465'` to `$config['smtp_port'] = 465`

Comment: Also `$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");` after you initialize(); seems to help according to this thread http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/84689/

Comment: added both changes the `$config['smtp_port'] = 465` and `$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");` to still an error showing up as `The following SMTP error was encountered: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error. s39sm7641969wfc.4 
data: 503 5.5.1 RCPT first. s39sm7641969wfc.4
The following SMTP error was encountered: 503 5.5.1 RCPT first. s39sm7641969wfc.4 
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. s39sm7641969wfc.4 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. s39sm7641969wfc.4 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.`

Comment: this problem is causing me so many headaches, thanks so far Ben for you help

Comment: Is SSL enabled in your php.ini? Load up php.ini and find a line with the following:

;extension=php_openssl.dll

if there is a semi-colon then remove it and restart apache

Comment: and if all that doesn't work then it could be a problem with the initialize() function that's been a known bug in CI. Remove the original `$this->load->library("email")` line from your controller and then replace the `$this->email->initialize($config)` line in the send function to `$this->load->library("email", $config)`

Comment: once again added your solutions but unfortunetly came to another road block as the i still recieve the error `Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.`

I just dont get it, is there another email addon I could possibly use? thanks for your help though @Ben

Comment: You send your email via PHP's `mail` function instead of using SMTP. Have you really changed 'protocal' to 'protocol', as Ben Stephenson suggested? If you really use SMTP, then Codeigniter does not use the mail function, but `fsockopen()` et al, see https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/src/fa2ee6e30941/system/libraries/Email.php

Comment: I found my problem, it was to do with the $user_email variable not actually being set. Its all good now and it works at intended thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the rest of the function you're using to send the email, everything you've posted looks correct... the `Message: Undefined index: Subject` is coming from somewhere else and might be causing problems.

Also... this may seem obvious, but you have actually loaded the email class somewhere, right (`$this->load->library('email);`)... rather than just initialized it?

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
    $config = array('auth' => 'login',
        'username' => '***@gmail.com',
        'password' => '***password',
        'port' => '465',
        'ssl' => 'ssl');


    $request = $this->getRequest();


    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            try {
                $smtpHost = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
                $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                $mail->setBodyText($form->getValue('body'));
                $mail->setBodyHtml('');
                $mail->setFrom();
                $mail->addTo());
                $mail->setSubject('');
                $mail->send($smtpHost);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die($e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, this code uses the Zend Framework rather than Codeigniter.