# How to set custom error handler in Codeigniter to Email errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm fairly new to PHP and the setting of custom error handlers, but I have some code which works fine outside of CI but I can't work out how to integrate this into a CI Controller. I get an error "Message: Undefined property: Errors::$my_error_handler"

My Controller is:

```
<?php
class Errors extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function my_error_handler($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars)
    {
        $email = "
            <p>An error ($number) occurred on line
            <strong>$line</strong> and in the <strong>file: $file.</strong>
            <p> $message </p>";

        $email .= "<pre>" . print_r($vars, 1) . "</pre>";

        $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        // Email the error to someone...
        error_log($email, 1, 'name@domain.com', $headers);

        // Make sure that you decide how to respond to errors (on the user's side)
        // Either echo an error message, or kill the entire project. Up to you...
        // The code below ensures that we only "die" if the error was more than
        // just a NOTICE.
        if ( ($number !== E_NOTICE) && ($number < 2048) ) {
            die("There was an error. Please try again later.");
        }
    }


    function test()
    {
        // We should use our custom function to handle errors.
        set_error_handler($this->my_error_handler);

        // Trigger an error... (var doesn't exist)
        echo $somevarthatdoesnotexist;

    }

}
?>
```

If there is a better way to email error messages using CI please let me know.

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403571/codeigniter-email-error-handling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that extending CI_Controller is the right way to solve this. Instead you should extend CI_Logs to send an e-mail, whenever an error is logged:

```
class MY_Log extends CI_Log {

    function MY_Log(){

        parent::__construct();

    }

    function write_log($level = 'error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE){

        $result = parent::write_log($level, $msg, $php_error);

        if ($result == TRUE && strtoupper($level) == 'ERROR') {

            $message = "An error occurred: \n\n";
            $message .= $level.' - '.date($this->_date_fmt). ' --> '.$msg."\n";

            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $to = $this->CI->config->item('email_admin_address');
            $from_name = $this->CI->config->item('email_general_name');
            $from_address = $this->CI->config->item('email_general_address');

            $subject = 'An error has occured';
            $headers = "From: $from_name <$from_address>" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n';

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        }

        return $result;

    }
```

}

Save this class to application\libraries\MY_Logs.php and don't forget to enable error logging in your config.php: `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;`

Kudos to [WPStorm](http://wpstorm.net/2009/05/email-log-messages-library-codeigniter/), who came up with this idea first.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.

```
set_error_handler(array(&$this, 'my_error_handler'));
```

Since you have to tell the error-handler that it is a class-method you want to call (intended meaning of `set_error_handler(array(&$this, ‘method’))`) and not just a function (intended meaning of `set_error_handler(‘function’)`)

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the core exceptions class you will be able to add the required functionality within that.

[Codeigniter forum post on extending that class](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/67096/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Michael. Yes that has pointed me in the right direction to email all errors, but I also need to be able to do a database update if an error occurs in a specific Method of a Controller. I'm thinking I probably don't need to adjust the Exceptions Class to do this. What do you suggest?