# Send email with Gmail not work | codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, gmail

this is my code to send email with gmail but it is not work , I am try hard to make it work for 4 days but still not work.

please help me, it was work before 6 day , after that not work , the server told me to change PHPMailer to SMTP Gmail , I am changed but still not work ...

i am register in Amazon SES Email , but i do not know how to use it, so i have 2 option : make this run in my normal server or change to Amazon SES , if SES is better chance learn me how to use it .

[my site to test](http://stirox.com/emailsms/)

> my Controller

```
 public function Send_Single_Email_Try ()
 {

 $email_config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'xx@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xx',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $email_config);
    $this->email->from('someuser@gmail.com', 'invoice');
    $this->email->to('test@test.com');
    $this->email->subject('Invoice');
    $this->email->message('Test');

    $this->email->send();
            if($send)
            { 

                echo 1;
            }
            else
            {
                echo 0;

            }
}
```

> my JS

```
   $(document).on('click','#SendEmailTry',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

         $.ajax({

        url:"<?php echo 
  base_url('Email/Send_Single_Email_Try/')?>",

        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",

        success:function(data)
                  {
                     if (data == 1)
                      {
                        alert("send");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                         alert("notsend");
                      }


                  },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                 {

                          alert("error")


                 }

            });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

> $this->load->library('email');
>
> $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
>
> $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
>
> $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
>
> $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
>
> $config['smtp_user']    = 'sender_mailid@gmail.com';
>
> $config['smtp_pass']    = 'password';
>
> $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
>
> $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
>
> $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html
>
> $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not
>
> $this->email->initialize($config);
>
> $this->email->from('sender_mailid@gmail.com', 'sender_name');
>   $this->email->to('recipient@gmail.com');
>
> $this->email->subject('Email Test');
>
> $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
>
> $this->email->send();
>
> echo $this->email->print_debugger();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403571/codeigniter-email-error-handling --i think may be this link can help you.

Answer (score -1):

1. check and set your csrf protection from your site config file(yourproject/config/config.php) such as,

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;

2. your rewrite code:

   ```
   public function Send_Single_Email_Try ()    
   {
   $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);    
   $email_config = Array(    
   'protocol'  => 'smtp',    
   'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',    
   'smtp_port' => '465',    
   'smtp_user' => 'xx@gmail.com',    
   'smtp_pass' => 'xx',    
   'mailtype'  => 'html',    
   'starttls'  => true,    
   'newline'   => "\r\n"    
   );

   $this->load->library('email', $email_config);
   $this->email->from('someuser@gmail.com', 'invoice');
   $this->email->to('test@test.com');
   $this->email->subject('Invoice');
   $this->email->message('Test');

   $send = $this->email->send();
   if($send)
   { 

   echo 1;
   }
   else
   {
   echo 0;
   }
   }
   ```